# Defer (async) Blogger comment_from_post_iframe.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, comments, blogger, deferred

I'm trying to superoptimize the blog [marketmovers](https://www.marketmovers.it)... after removing all unnecessary plugins, unwanted blogger CSS and JS, now pagespeed insight reports a problem that I can not solve and for which I did not find documentation: defer /2567313873-comment_from_post_iframe.js.

By chance there is someone who has already solved this problem or can you help me?

Ps. disable blogger comments is not a valid solution for me because I want to keep the system from leaving a comment

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary solution for that. You need to change the  tag with the given code

```
&lt;!--</body> --&gt; &lt;/body&gt;
```

It will definitely improve page speed by 5 to 6 points.